# AHK Pause\Play youtube in an unfocused chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, autohotkey

I want to pause and play a youtube video that I have playing with a shortcut key when it's not focused playing in the background. but I have trouble understanding how can I target chrome and one of its tabs.

Press shortcut key
sends "spacebar" key to chrome youtube tab.

It's seems simple but I'm quite new to this any help appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible unless you find some Chrome extension that has a hotkey to pause/unpause a video in any tab. Then you'll be able to send that key to Chrome in AutoHotkey. I'm not posting it as an answer because I don't want to search for such an extension, sorry.

Comment: well I want it to use for youtube, where you can literally use "spacebar" to pause/play a video @wOxxOm , so I find it weird that it's impossible without an extension.

Comment: Chrome doesn't expose any externally accessible means of controlling itself or the content. While you can send hotkeys to an active tab but when the tab isn't active there's nothing you can do without a special extension that exposes the required means of automation such as a hotkey, for example. Nothing weird here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A raw working script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

ControlGet, OutputVar, Hwnd,,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, Google Chrome

ControlFocus,,ahk_id %outputvar%

Loop {
    IfWinExist, YouTube
        break

    ControlSend, , ^{PgUp} , Google Chrome
    sleep 300
}
ControlSend, , {Space} , Google Chrome
```

`ctrl + PgUp` is used to circle through the tabs, until a youtube tab is found, then `space` is send to chrome. You have to adjust the sleep timer to your system.

Not having a youtube tab or no Chrome at all will result in an infinite loop. Include safety checks!

Comment: I noticed one problem though, I have 2 separate chrome windows open. One which has youtube video playing and another where several other tabs are - -  Now let's say I have my youtube open and playing and then another chrome browser open for testing/reading and sublime  focused for writing stuff and when I press my hotkey, it activates the non-youtube chome window. Any workaround? @Schneyer

Comment: If you dont need the tab search (because the "youtube" Chrome has only one tab), you can skip the loop and use "YouTube" instead of "Google Chrome" in `ControlGet` and `ControlSend`. You can use the Window Spy tool, which comes with AHK to determine the titles yourself.

Comment: @Schneyer @Helpme your tab search is awesome! I love that idea. maybe it would be good to count the amount of `^{pgup}` presses, so they can be undone after the `controlsend {space}` via `^{pgdown}`

Answer (score 1):

This will play/pause a youtube video when not in chrome and pressing alt+shift+p, useful for listening music on youtube.
It will find the youtube tab, play/pause and then return to your working tab all in the background

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
controlID := 0
tabCount := 0
#IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
; Play/pause
+!p::
    ControlGet, controlID, Hwnd,,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, Google Chrome
    ControlFocus,,ahk_id %controlID%
    IfWinExist, YouTube
    {
        ControlSend, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, k , Google Chrome
        return
    }
    tabCount := 0
    Loop {
        IfWinExist, YouTube
            break
        ControlSend, , ^{PgUp} , Google Chrome
        sleep 150
    tabCount := tabCount + 1
    if tabCount > 10
      return
    }
    ControlSend, , k , Google Chrome
    Loop, %tabCount% {
        ControlSend, , ^{PgDn} , Google Chrome
        sleep 150
    }
    return
#IfWinNotActive
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
DetectHiddenWindows, On
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

controlN := 0

return

#IfWinNotActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
z & space::
    chromeSend("{Space}")
return


z & right::
    chromeSend("{Right}")
return

z & left::
    chromeSend("{Left}")
return

chromeSend(keys)
{
    ControlGet, controlN, Hwnd,,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, Google Chrome
    ControlFocus,,ahk_id %controlN%
    Sleep, 50
    ControlSend, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, %keys% , Google Chrome
}



#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
z & space::
    chromeSend("k")
return


z & right::
    chromeSend("{Right}")
return

z & left::
    chromeSend("{Left}")
return
```

Using this code you can control youtube using z + space/arrows.